# how to remove the extension of a found file FSO?

Tags: vba

The code I wrote can display filenames into a sheet, but I want to remove the extension when displayed. I know that should be a little correction, but I burned out trying options. Can Somebody tell me where exaclty I must add a piece of code that I miss please? My attempt of code below. Many similar issues on the net, but I can not manage to find it.Thanks in advance....

```
Option Explicit
Sub fileNames_in_folder()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Dim fldpath
Dim fld As Object, fil As Object, fso As Object, j As Long
 fldpath = "C:\"
   On Error Resume Next
Thisworkbook.Sheets("1").Activate
'start count row
    j = 11
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fld = fso.getfolder(fldpath)
    For Each fil In fld.Files
'here I have to add something due to expell the ".extension" 
Cells(j, 34).Value = fso.GetBaseName(fil.path)
'count behaviour
    j = j + 1
  Next
Columns("AH").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: let's make it clear- you want to keep whole path+file name except file extension?

Comment: I updated the code! Thanks to Ivan this works like a spear!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A file name without extension you can get with [GetBaseName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhxzwwe1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
Cells(j, 34).Value = fso.GetBaseName(fil.path)
```

Comment: Hi Ivan! YOU ROCK!!!!!! Thanks a lot!!!! This is doiing EXACTLY what is suppose to do! What a beautiful solution!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
If InStrRev(fil.Path, ".") <> 0 Then
   Cells(j, 34).Value = Left(fil.Path, InStrRev(fil.Path, ".") - 1)
End If
```

Assuming the presence "." in the file name.
i.e. C:\Test.txt will be shown as C:\Test

Comment: What if there is more than one "." in the filename or even in a folder name? E.g. C:\tst.pp\MyFile

Comment: The code looks for the first dot from the back. I am assuming that the file names with multiple dots will be handled. for e.g. c:\test.xml.txt should return c:\test.xml.

Comment: Hi Shahkalpesh, Thank you for responding so fast! Your code is displaying the path when I fill that in. In my code only the filename with extension is displaying, but I want to remove also the extension :-). Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't noticed 'Rev' but still there is a problem with dot in a folder name not and not in the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but Ivan gave the right solution already!