# How to rename a file using the existing text + character in VB

Tags: vb.net, rename

I am trying to rename a file like this:

T003_TAR_Witness Stmt Summary_190624_GOODYEAR.pdf

To the following:

T003_TAR_Witness Stmt Summary_190624_GOODYEAR_ADTC.pdf

I have this so far to remove the file extension, but need something in the middle to add the "_ADTC"

---

```
'Lets rename the original file and mark so no dupulcate disclosues
onlyFile = Left(xFile.Name, InStrRev(xFile.Name, ".") - 1) 'Removes the file extension     
'find the code to add "_ADTC" to the end of the file name
fileExt = Right(xFile.Name, Len(xFile.Name) - InStrRev(xFile.Name, ".")) 'gets just the file extension
```

---

To be clear, I need to keep the original file name, add the text and put the extension back on. 
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove the extension of a found file FSO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763675/how-to-remove-the-extension-of-a-found-file-fso)

Answer (score 2):

```
Using System.IO

Dim oldFilename As String = "T003_TAR_Witness Stmt Summary_190624_GOODYEAR.pdf"
Dim newFilename As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldFileName) & _
                            "_ADTC" & _
                            Path.GetExtension(oldFilename)
```